# Populating dropdown list from array working on JSFiddle but not working on local machine?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, appendchild

Hey everyone I am trying to populate dropdown list with array but it is not working but is working fine when I use the same code on JSFiddle. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use alert boxes like given below

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    alert();
    select.appendChild(el);
    alert();
}
```

The first alert box appears but the second alert box does not appear ie only first iteration of loop is running which terminates at select.appendChild(el);.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: @ Arg0n  No no errors or warnings on console. But being a newbie I am not sure I am looking at right place I go to inspect element then choose Console tab which is empty.

Comment: @Arg0n I receive following error TypeError: select is null[Learn More] on console when I refreshed the page.

Comment: Then there's your problem. You have no element with `id` `selectNumber` in your HTML.

Comment: Could you link us to a jsfiddle with the exact same code you are using?

Comment: Acctually, the problem is that your JavaScript runs before the `selectNumber` `input` is on the page. Place your JavaScript after your HTML. Or put it inside some `document.ready`.

Comment: @Arg0n Thank you that solved the problem

Comment: Also, as you are including jquery why not use it? `$('selectNumber').append($('<option>', {value:options[i], text:options[i]}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your JavaScript code in document.ready function like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
});
</script>
```

Your values were not appending because the DOM was initialized after the script was executed. It is a good practice to put your code in document.ready function.